# sizeof of two template types, when both are derived from one base

Tags: c++, c++11

Sample code

```
#include <iostream>

struct base {};

template<typename Type>
struct left : base {

   Type value;
};

template<typename Type>
struct right : base {

   Type value;
}; 

int main() {
   std::cout << "sizeof left<base> = " << sizeof(left<base>) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof left<right<base>>    = " << sizeof(left<right<base>>) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "sizeof left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>> = " << sizeof(left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>>) << std::endl;
}
```

Output

With GCC 4.6 is

```
sizeof left<base> = 2  
sizeof left<right<base>>    = 3  
sizeof left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>> = 6
```

With clang 3.1

```
sizeof left<base> = 2  
sizeof left<right<base>>    = 3  
sizeof left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>> = 6
```

With MSVC 2012

```
sizeof left<base> = 1
sizeof left<right<base>>    = 1
sizeof left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>> = 1
```

So, question is, is it bug in GCC/clang, or is it implementation defined, or is it right output (quotes from standard, or explanations of such behaviour will be nice)

Comment: Even for a standalone class or structure the standard does not mandate the size to be anything specific. It is always summation of size required for members + Any padding + Anything what compiler desires. So this cannot be a bug. The size aspect is strictly implementation defined.

Comment: @Als When applied
to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for
placing objects of that type in an array.
What do you mean as "anything what compiler desires"?

Comment: It is a placeholder. It can be literally anything up to the wish and free will of the compiler implementation.

Comment: See [Should an empty base class affect the layout of the derived class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760198/should-an-empty-base-class-affect-the-layout-of-the-derived-class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant quote is 1.8 [intro.object] paragraph 6:

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

In your `right<T>` and `left<T>` object (why have to different class templates? One should have been enough) you each have a member `value` (of type `T`). Each one needs to get its own unique address. Thus,

```
sizeof(left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>>) == 1
```

is definitely wrong! There are 6 distinct objects:

- 5 `value`s
- one `left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>>`

and only the `left<right<left<right<left<base>>>>>` and one of its subjects the (the first `value` if I recall other rules) can share an address. That is, the size of the object needs to be at least 5. Since objects work best when aligned it seems to get padded to 6 bytes (which is odd; I'd expect it to be padded to a multiple of 4).

Even size of `left<base>` could't be `1`: There are two `base` objects involved already! One in the form of the base class of `lef<base> and one in form of a member of this class. These two`base` objects need distinct addresses and, thus, the size needs to be at least 2.

In any case, object sizes only have requirements how big they are at least. They don't have any requirement that they shall not be bigger than something. This is considered a quality of implementation issue. Based on this, the only compiler being wrong (assuming the sizes quotes are, indeed, correct) is MSVC++. The other sizes may sometimes be slightly bigger than desired but this isn't an error.

Comment: `The size of left<base> could be 1` It cannot be `1` because if EBO was employed, you could have two objects of the same type have the same address (see the linked question in the comments).

Comment: Oh, right: `left<base>::value` cannot have the same address as `left<base>` because it would imply that the base of `left<base>`, i.e., `base`, is the same object as the only member but this is clearly not the case. Nice catch...!

Comment: whatever he did catch, it is advisable to fix your answer rather than doing so in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

the GCC behavior is strange but sizeof is totally a compiler issue, so it merely depends on how the compiler as said 
you may try

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

and see the results again