# How to explain this sizeof result when inheriting from an empty class

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

Suppose I have the following C++ definitions of structs.

```
struct Empty {};
struct Tmp : public Empty { int x; };
struct Tmp2 : public Empty { Tmp tmp;};
struct Tmp3 { Tmp tmp; };
```

The `sizeof(Tmp3) == sizeof(Tmp) == 4`, which is expected.
However, `sizeof(Tmp2) == 8`, I can't think of why...? Could you help to explain? Thanks!

Comment: What compiler are you using? With MSVC I get 4 for all of them and 1 for sizeof(Empty),

Comment: @BarmakShemirani MSVC is not a good compiler to test with if you want anything even *slightly* resembling standards-compliance.

Comment: A size of 4 can actually be standards-compliant, it depends on whether the two `Empty` subobjects have the same or different addresses. What's the output of `Tmp2 t; cout << static_cast<Empty*>(&t) << static_cast<Empty*>(&t.tmp);`?

Comment: @o11c, what exactly MSVC violated in this case?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I just tried on [the online MSVC compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) and they have the same address.

Comment: @o11c This is basically undefined behaviour, I don't know what's the difference (and I don't care), I just asked what compiler is used.

Answer (score 15):

In the case of `Tmp`, the [*empty base class optimization* (EBCO)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is permitted and your compiler is applying it.

In the case of `Tmp2`, the EBCO is disabled because the data member `Tmp2::tmp` is also an `Empty`. This is because `Tmp2` has two sub-objects of the same type (the base class sub-object and its first data member). These must have distinct addresses<sup>*</sup>. Otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish one from the other.

This means the base class contributes to the derived class' size.

---

<sup>* From **1.8 The C++ Object Model**: "*Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.*"</sup>

Comment: Why they **must** have distinct addresses?

Comment: @ixSci It is specified in the standard. I added a footnote with a quote.

Comment: I have hard time deciphering this phrase, would you mind help me a little? "Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other" - ok, `tmp` is a subobject of the `Tmp2` . "or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types" - `Empty` is a base class subobject of `Tmp2`. `Tmp` and `Empty` are different types. Why they can't have the same address?

Comment: @ixSci The example is is a bit complicated by nesting, but `Tmp` is an `Empty`, so its first sub-object is an `Empty` object. That sub-object has the same address as the `Tmp` sub-object of `Tmp2`, and it must be distinct from the address of the base subobject of `Tmp2`.

Comment: @ixSci: The important thing to take home is that distinct objects of the same type _always_ have distinct addresses, and two objects not both related to other (parent) objects also always have distinct addresses. The sentence narrows in the "allowed equal addresses" cases even a bit more. In the example, supposing `Tmp2 x;`, one must have `&static_cast<Empty&>(x)!= &static_cast<Empty&>(x.tmp)`, which is comparing the addresses of two distinct objects of the same type.

Comment: Thanks, I reread it as well as other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760198/should-an-empty-base-class-affect-the-layout-of-the-derived-class) by @BoPersson and I think I understand it now. Still the phrase in the standard might be clearer because for me it is not clear at all.

Comment: BTW, how about the following statement on the same page of the standard: "Under the “as-if” rule an implementation is allowed to store two objects at the same machine address or not store an object at all if the program cannot observe the difference". In my opinion it proves that MSVC doesn't have a bug. @BoPersson?

Comment: @ixSci I think it is a bug, because the size of a type is a compile time constant, and giving it a size of 4 would mean that no code that uses that type could ever take the addresses of the sub-objects, for example.

Comment: @ixSci: that sentence of the standard is quite clear (at least compared to many others), but you might appreciate it more by rewriting it as contrapositive: two objects that are not bit-fields must have distinct addresses unless they have distinct types and either one is a subobject of the other or at least one is a base class subobject of zero size. (I've moved "distinct types" a level up since y being a proper subobject of x implies that x and y have distinct types).

Answer (score 5):

The rule is that two different objects of the same type must have different addresses, which is also the reason that an empty object still has a positive size. Since this only applies to objects of the same type, two different types can share storage, which is the foundation of the "Empty Baseclass Optimization".

Now, your `Tmp` contains (as baseclass) an `Empty` subobject. Further, `Tmp2` has two such subobjects, one via its baseclass, the other as plain member. Also, it has an `int`. For that reason, you need more space than just for the `int`, i.e. `sizeof (int) + 1` at least. Probably due to padding, it then ends up with eight bytes.

BTW: Consider a `Tmp4`, which inherits from `Tmp` and also contains a `Tmp`. That one will probably have the same size as `Tmp2`.

Comment: "The rule is that two different objects of the same type must have different addresses" can you prove this statement? In regard to the layout in question, of course

Comment: I can't pull the proper verse and chapter of the C++ Standard from my sleve that proves this, I'd need to do some research for that. However, you are asking for a prove in the context of the "layout in question" (`Tmp2`'s?), which I don't understand as a question, because the general rule can't be proven except by deduction from the C++ Standard and that again is independent of the layout here...

Comment: As far as I can tell the layout in question violates rules for the standard layout. So it makes it non-standard, hence non-POD. But I do not see anything in the standard which would forbid such a layout

Comment: `Tmp2` layout is not standard layout because of `9/7`(`has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member`)

Comment: @ixSci - Two different objects of the same type must have different addresses, otherwise you cannot tell them apart. Objects of *different* types, like a struct and its first member, can have the same address.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a horrible nonstandard hack** ... but if for some reason you *want* `sizeof(Tmp2) == 4`, there is a way that works in all compilers I've tested.

```
struct EvilEmpty
{
    char evil[0];
};
```

By providing an illegal (but widely accepted as an extension) zero-size array as a member, it is no longer seen as empty, and the compiler is tricked into not realizing that it might illegally place two distinct objects with the same class at the same address. (Note, this is *smaller* than a legal empty class.)

Obviously, this is prone to all the problems that led both the C and C++ standards to forbid zero-sized objects in the *first* place.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not the question as phrased, but perhaps the question that was intended. If not by OP, perhaps by someone else searching for this.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: It still contributes to the post. I usually start such answers (and I did have some in the past) with: "Not a direct answer to your question, but...".